# How to bypass authentication/authorization on a resource using JHipster microservice + gateway?

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

We are implementing microservices with JHipster and we have a scenario where we need a specific resource in one of our microservices to be available via Gateway without the need for authorization/authentication.
What sort of configuration should be done in the microservice app or gateway in order to achieve such behavior?

Comment: Have you tried calling permitAll() on your resource URL in SecurityConfiguration.java of your microservice?

Comment: We are calling permitAll()  on our resource but in the Gateway, if placed in the microservice it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by it does not work? Please edit your question with more details, which resource url, ..... Also, I suspect that you are talking only about authorization but that in fact you want to disable also authentication. I answered only about authorization.

Comment: Yes, we need the resource to be accessible without authentication/authorization, by changing only the microservice app I still get a 401 error while trying to access the resource, that's why we changed the gateway config.

Comment: Thanks for having clarified in comments but you did not edit your question as requested. Your question still lacks details like what you modified on gateway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give access to the resource on that microservice, so the resource is accessible from the gateway without authentication.
In you microservice, edit SecuritConfiguration exclude service from `.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()` and add ,for example, `.antMatchers("/api/service1").permitAll()` line before that.